# github action slowness causing cypress test case to fail

Tags: cypress, github-actions

Github action is working slow as compared to my local and  TC gets failed in github action, can anyone pls suggest if i can run on some specific server or put timeout in github action yaml file below is my github action yaml file

```
name: Cypress Tests

on: push

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          record: true
          browser: chrome
          spec: cypress/e2e/Customer.cy.js
        env:
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Do you have any details of the test and the part that fails? I don't think the GA has settings that can work like that.

Comment: It fails when i save form and when for successful message it gives below error : 


 1) Customer Page - Partner
       Create New customer:
     AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 90000ms: Expected to find element: `//p[text()='Customer created successfully!']`, but never found it.

@T.Soithongsuk

Answer (score 5):

The xpath code you have (given in comments) is now deprecated in Cypress, although it will probably still work if you downgrade the Cypress version.

But instead, use standard CSS selectors which are easier in any case.

The way to solve your timeout problem with GH is simply to increase the command timeout.

For example (assuming your code fragment is part of the test):

```js
cy.contains('p', 'Customer created successfully!', {timeout: 10_000})
```

Be aware that CI can take longer to run initial tests, you will *possibly* only need the extended timeout on the first assertion in the spec.